# How to overcome ArrayList String delimiting " " and ' '?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have an array list defined as

```
List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I am adding other strings to this List this way

```
  cmd.add("/c");
  cmd.add(command);
```

However if command contains " " or ' ' and a white space in between them the quotes are truncated.
How do I workaround this behaviour?

For example, if the command is

`grep "Hello world" /sratch/temp`

the cmd contains these Strings  `/c  grep  Hello  World  /scratch/temp`

However if the command is  `grep "Hello\ world" /sratch/temp`

the strings in cmd are

`/c  grep " Hello  World " /scratch/temp`

How do I program it such that the " " are not truncated?

Comment: I think there is missing information here. Where do the strings come from? In your second example there are quotes, are you saying the quotes are not kept together with the `Hello World`? Can you show us the code that fills in the `cmd`?

Comment: provided through the UI. I have a jsp page for this

Comment: yes. provided through the UI. I have a jsp page for thi

Comment: JSP? OK, please edit your question using the `edit` link, and add your JSP form and the servlet code that takes the data and puts it in the `cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

So you want your `String` object to contain quotes? Try escaping them with backslash:

`cmd.add("some string with \"quotes\"");`

Comment: yes. As a work around I am providing the input as grep "Hello\ world" /sratch/temp. However I want the java program to take care of this and not the user

Comment: @user2834526 So how do you tell the difference between `"Hello"` which means `Hello` or `"Hello"`?

Comment: Simply if you want Hello you type "Hello" if you "Hello" you type "\"Hello\""

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not related to `ArrayList`, you simple have to escape your single and double quotes when you assign them to the `String` object or retrieve them from user input. For more information on escape sequences in Java, have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) on the Oracle web site, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the quotes, just write:

```
"grep \"Hello world\" /sratch/temp"
```

You can take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), for more information

**EDIT**
If you're parsing the user input Java will escape this special characters automatically. For example, with this code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input:"+s);
    }
}
```

And the input: `Testing "Quotes"`

You will get this String:

[image]

Comment: yes. but then I want the program to do it. not the input. the inout may or maynot contain the "" . For eg: the input could simply be ls -l .

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, those commands are introduced by you or by the user?

Comment: the commands are provided by the user. Some commands have " " and some do not. The proble here is that the " " are always escaped. I do not want them to be escaped. I want the program to handle this.

Comment: I think Java will interpret the input with the special characters automatically, if it doesn't do it automatically please post the code where you read the user input.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not about Java, but about the shell you're using.

On the shell (i.e. bash, command prompt, etc.) arguments are generally broken up using spaces.

For instance,

```
java my.class The quick brown fox
```

would result in an argument list of

```
String[] { "The", "quick", "brown", "fox" }
```

However, the shell usually allows the user to make multiple spaced strings a single argument by surrounding them with double quotes - the behavior you're seeing.

For instance,

```
java my.class The quick "brown fox"
```

would result in an argument list of

```
String[] { "The", "quick", "brown fox" }
```

This means double quotes are removed from the argument list and are *not* literally inserted into the string.

---

If my assumption is correct, and you're running shell commands via your program given some sort of other command system, then you can simply surround *every* piece of the command in double quotes.